# how to get machine name on which website is running

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem in which I have one table having column server name. I am passing server name as parameter to Stored Procedure which will update this table. 
Please let me know, how should I get this server name in `ASP.NET MVC3` code on which site is running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from `Request.Url.Host` or somewhere around that. ie: bu parsing the URL into parts.

Comment: Is there any way to get this data from Web.config file?

Comment: not sure, why you wanna do that? you can read it from app settings, too. Look at `ConfigurationManager.AppSetting['Key']`

Comment: what should be the key in this case ?

Comment: whatever you define in your AppSettings

Comment: we can use Environment.MachineName :)

Comment: Request.Url.Host does not have to match the actual server name of the machine. If you need that then Environment.MachineName is the most accurate way to do that. Although i am very curious why you would need that for data access purposes.